# yii2 run module command from console

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I can't correctly run module command from console

Here the controller, which I want to run:

[image]

Trying to run it as:

```
./yii iiko/import/import-contacts-first
```

But getting error: `Unknown command: iiko/import/import-contacts-first`

What is the correct way to run the action from this controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a controllerMap entry in your console config file (`config/console.php` in yii2-app-basic):

```
$config = [
    'id'        => 'your-app-id',
    '...
    'controllerMap' => [
        'iikoImport' => [
            'class' => 'common\crm\modules\iiko\controllers\ImportController',
        ],
    ]
    ...
```

Then you can try:

```
yii iiko-import/action-name
```